# I'm trying to use list comprehenison with numpy arrays, generating a single generator expression within a numpy array. Why?

Tags: arrays, numpy, list-comprehension, generator-expression

so I'm writing some code that's going to be deployed on a raspberry pi. Because of the computational limitations of the raspberry pi, and the series of steps it's taking for this particular use(image capturing and processing) I thought it would be best to use list comprehension in place of for loops whenever possible. I managed to create a statement that made an array of files(names+paths), if it worked:

> self.dark_file_names=np.array([(os.path.join(self.dark_frames_path,
>    line.strip("\n")) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dark_frames_path) for line in files  if line.endswith(".npy\n"))])

however, I tried a variation of this in ipython:

> dark_file_names=np.array([(os.path.join(dark_frames_path, line.strip("\n")) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dark_frames_path) for line in files  if line.endswith(".py\n"))])

with this being the output:

```
array([<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f14d4412888>], dtype=object)
```

with dark_frames_path being a local directory with a ton of python files

unfortunately this isn't what I was hoping for. I also tried with a normal list with a similar result. Why is it interpreting my statement as a generator expression instead of a list comprehension?

also I had this working when I was doing it over ssh with these commands in ipython:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr= ssh.exec_command('ls')

l=[line.strip('\n') for line in stdout if line.strip('\n').endswith(".py")]
```

with ssh being a paramiko.SSHClient() instance.

Comment: A list comprehension is a loop; slightly faster than the explicit equivalent, but not drastically so.  And because of its syntax, some things are harder to do, even impossible.  Also do you need to turn this into an array; why not leave it as a list?  Another complaint - it's unreadable.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's different between the variations by just reading.  I'd have to copy them to an editor, and edit it for readability.  You are aware that replacing `[]` of a list comprehension can turn it into a generator expression?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `()` surrounding `os.path.join(...)`?

Comment: hey thank you. I figured out what was wrong. it was partly the () around the entire function that I forgot about, and partly the newline sequence. /n was necessary when I was running these commands over ssh using paramiko because of the return value of one of the functions, and for some reason I left it in there.

Comment: For future viewers this is the version that worked `self.dark_file_names=np.array([os.path.join(self.dark_frames_path,line) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dark_frames_path) for line in files  if line.endswith(".npy")])`
this created an array of all the numpy files